# android.os.FileUriExposedException in unity for Android +7.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I want to share a screenshot with a text in unity

```
AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + screenshotadress);

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), "text");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), "Subject");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/jpeg");

AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");    
currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

it's worked in android 6.0 and lower, in 7.0 and higher how i can use this file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FileProvider` class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps over API 23.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)

Comment: Hi do you have Documentation for Unity 3d?